# Displaying an XML file on a view in ASP.Net MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am relatively new when it comes to asp.net MVC 5 and I am trying to display the contents of an xml file ( which is located in the content folder of my project for ease of access) and display the contents on a simple view. the code from my controller, modelclass and view are below.....

The Error I am getting is as follows

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[XML_v1._0.Models.XML_details]'.

---

The code for my controller, modelclass and view are below.....

## The View

```html
@model IEnumerable<XML_v1._0.Models.XML_details>


}
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        th {
            font-size: 300%;
        }

        td {
            font-size: 300%;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<h2>Line Status</h2>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Line)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
            </th>


        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Line)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                </td>
   
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>
```

## The Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using XML_v1._0.Models;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Dynamic;


namespace XML_v1._0.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       public ActionResult Index()
        {
            XDocument L_tube = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\070339\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Learning and practice\XML v1.0\XML v1.0\Content\tube.xml");
            var train = from s in L_tube.Descendants() select s;


            var model = train.ToList();

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

## The Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;

namespace XML_v1Models
{
    public partial class  XML_details
    {
        public XmlElement Line { get; set; }
        public XmlElement Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You pasted your Controller code into the Model code section. Either way, the controller is returning a `List<XElement>` in its model but the view is expecting an `IEnumerable<XML_details>`. You need to create your model based on the list you loaded.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `return view()` in your controller you should pass it a variable of type `IEnumerable<XML_v1._0.Models.XML_details>`. So basically your  controller would 
do the following

```
IEnumerable<XML_v1._0.Models.XML_details> model = (from s in
 L_tube.Descendants() select s);
```

and then do the

```
return View(model);
```